# How to allow embedding of a site with PHP and an iframe

Tags: php

In a situation where I control two separate websites on an intranet, I want to embed a page from one of them into an iframe on the other. I control both, they are both internal to my network and inaccessible from the outside world.

When trying to embed the first in an iframe to the second I get an error in Chrome that says:

*Refused to display 'http://mywebsiteurl/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.*

I've tried setting this header on top of the PHP page:

`<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");  ?>`

but it didn't change anything.

What settings do I need to set on the website in order to allow it to be embedded elsewhere? I'm using Apache and PHP. I control both and I want them to be allowed to embed. It looks like x-frame-options only has two settings; DENY which I don't want and SAMEORIGIN which is also useless for me.

I should also mention the site with the iframe is a MediaWiki wite in case that helps determine what I need to do.

Comment: The error message mentions the [`X-Frame-Options` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options), which is entirely separate from the header you modified, [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin). Why not modify the header the error message says is problematic instead...? In a modern environment, you should be seeking to reconfigure the [`Content-Security-Policy` header value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) to allow this anyway.

Comment: Agreed, the error message mentions one header, so it's unclear why you decided to set a different one. Is it because it had the word "origin" in it? Instead of what is apparently some guesswork/assumption-making, try [googling the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Refused+to+display+in+a+frame+because+it+set+%27X-Frame-Options%27+to+%27sameorigin)

Comment: The header in the error message only has two possible options two possible options. DENY and SAMEORIGIN (both of which are not what we want). There seems to be no way to say Yes allow my page to be embedded with that header.

Comment: Sure, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options explains what to do instead of using the obsolete ALLOW-FROM directive.

Comment: unfortunately the ALLOW-FROM is not viable: 
The description says as much:  This is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers.

Comment: I know - see my updated comment, above. Or you should be able to simply omit the X-frame-options header entirely, I think, and then your site can be embedded anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`X-Frame-Options` is largely obsolete in modern browsers, replaced in favor of [Content Security Policy directives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). On both pages, you'll need to set specific directives to enable the design you describe:

- On the page where the `iframe` element is included, use [CSP: `frame-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src):

  ```
  Content-Security-Policy frame-src https://mywebsiteurl/
  ```
- On the page to be loaded as an `iframe` in the other (assuming the calling page with the above header is at URL `http://mywebsiteurl/path/to/iframe.html`), use [CSP: `frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors):

  ```
  Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors http://mywebsiteurl/path/to/iframe.html
  ```